# Storing complex React state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state, state-management, react-state-management

I have a React state that needs to be accessed/modified by a real time WebSocket connection and also a nested child component.

```js
import React from "react";
import Editor from "component/Editor";

function App() {
  let fileTreeData = [
    {
      id: 1,
      type: "directory",
      name: "Test Root",
      children: [
        { id: 2, type: "file", name: "Test 2" },
        {
          id: 3,
          type: "directory",
          name: "src",
          children: [
            { id: 4, type: "file", name: "index.js" },
            { id: 5, type: "file", name: "test.js" }
          ],
          expanded: false
        },
        { id: 6, type: "file", name: "Test" }
      ],
      expanded: true
    }
  ];

  return <Editor fileTreeData={fileTreeData} />;
}

export default App;
```

How would I go about implementing this in React? Global state seems to be an anti-pattern.

Comment: You can try using a redux store, how you update the data is not so important. Every update in the store triggers automatically updates in the components selectors

Comment: I'm not sue what you are asking, so `fileTreeData` can be changed by the user and changed by a websocket? And you want the `fileTreeData` to be available in multiple components?

Answer (score 0):

I would use [MobX](https://mobx.js.org/getting-started.html) for this purpose.

The pros:

- It is simple to implement.
- It has good performance.
- It is flexible in state definition.
- You can use MobX for only one component, not globally, as well as global state.

The cons:

- It is mutating the data so you have to follow the rules to have the correct state.
- It is very flexible, so you might misuse it.